# why would 10.255.0.1 appear in a tracert?

Tags: networking

I'm getting 10.255.0.1 as the 3rd item in a tracert to any website IP address from my computer. My LAN is 10.10.10.0/23. 10.255.0.1 doesn't seem to make sense as an IP on this network.
Can anyone shed light on what this might be?
Thanks
J

Comment: Why do you think it should make sense on your LAN? Your LAN itself may be behind one or more NATs (see [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)). What is the 1st and 2nd item?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are either on a mobile internet access or on a less often use of cable.

With both, an intermediary network of 10.x.x.x is used between the feeding point at the ISP side and your modem/router. With mobile, this is traditionally used to make cell-switchover (e.g. a driving car) easier to manage.

Comment: I am on ethernet from a desk, used daily. All private IP addresses on the network should begin with either 10.10.10 or 10.10.11.

Comment: Well it’s clearly not “on the network” (as in *your* network). Check your router for the “public IP” it reports.

Comment: Sebastian, this is not the network you are directly connected to, but an intermediary network used by your ISP outside of your sphere of influence. Thus 3rd on the traceroute, not 1st - it is completely independant of what your network admins chose for the LAN